# Android Login page design

Tags: android

I am android beginner. I want to create login page design (using user name password) retrieve data from a sqlite database. Can you help me? For example  like Gmail etc

Comment: Which kind of database do you mean? It it allready on the device?

Comment: Please refer http://developer.android.com/ to learn about database functionalities in android.

Comment: you should first learn database programming on your own in android after that you'll be able to do it your self...

Comment: here is the code to get u started.. has everything welcome screen & login ..stores data in sharedpref http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tablerow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tablerow1_tablelayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2_txtviewspace"
                            android:layout_width="30px"
                            android:layout_height="100px" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tablerow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tablerow2_tablelayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tablerow1_tablelayout1_tablerow1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow1_tablelayout1_tablerow1_viewspace1"
                            android:layout_width="30px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow1_tablelayout1_tablerow1_u_id"
                            android:layout_width="150px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="User Name: "
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow1_tablelayout1_tablerow1_viewspace2"
                            android:layout_width="30px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/loginedituid"
                            android:layout_width="200px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:maxLength="10"
                            android:singleLine="true" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tablerow2_tablelayout1_tablerow1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow2_tablelayout1_tablerow1_viewspace1"
                            android:layout_width="30px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow2_tablelayout1_tablerow1_pasword"
                            android:layout_width="150px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Password: "
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow2_tablelayout1_tablerow1_viewspace2"
                            android:layout_width="30px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editpswrd"
                            android:layout_width="200px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:maxLength="10"
                            android:singleLine="true" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow2_tablelayout1_tablerow1_viewspace3"
                            android:layout_width="30px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tablerow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tablerow3_tablelayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2_txtviewspace"
                            android:layout_width="10px"
                            android:layout_height="30px" />
                    </TableRow>


                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2_txtviewspace"
                            android:layout_width="30px"
                            android:layout_height="30px" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tablerow3_tablelayout1_tablerow1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tablerow3_tablelayout1_tablerow1_viewspace1"
                                android:layout_width="130px"
                                android:layout_height="30px" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
                                android:layout_width="150px"
                                android:layout_height="60px"
                                android:text="LOGIN"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tablerow3_tablelayout1_tablerow1_viewspace1"
                                android:layout_width="130px"
                                android:layout_height="30px" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnexit"
                                android:layout_width="150px"
                                android:layout_height="60px"
                                android:text="EXIT"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

This will be your login design.

Comment: Puh that is really much xml for a simple login. My login pages have much less xml code.

Comment: Yes this may be. As I have used TableLayout to make its looks better. Otherwise if device changes and resolution changes , Layout will be faded out.